# dynamic import json file

Tags: typescript, dynamic-import

I used to load a json file like this:

```
import faq from './faq.json'

interface FAQ {
   title: string
   body: string
}

interface SiteConfig {
    title: string
    faqs: FAQ[]
}

sites: {[key: string]: SiteConfig} = {
    siteA: {
        title: 'xx',
        faqs: faq
    }
}
```

Now I want to use dynamic imports:

```
interface FAQ {
   title: string
   body: string
}

interface SiteConfig {
    title: string
    faqs: () => FAQ[]
}

sites: {[key: string]: SiteConfig} = {
    siteA: {
        title: 'xx',
        faqs: (): Promise<FAQ[]> => import('./faq.json')
    }
}
```

fails with:

```
Type 'Promise<typeof "*.json">' is not assignable to type 'Promise<FAQ[]>'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript give you an error because `import` return a promise of type `JSON`, not `FAQ[]` and therefore your error.

Try instead:

```
sites: {[key: string]: SiteConfig} = {
    siteA: {
        title: 'xx',
        faqs: (): Promise<any> => import('./faq.json')
    }
}
```

You could also make `faqs` an async function

```
sites: {[key: string]: SiteConfig} = {
    siteA: {
        title: 'xx',
        faqs: async (): Promise<any> => await import('./faq.json')
    }
}
```